# linux tc qdisc pie (aqm) configuration with limited bandwidth

Tags: linux, traffic-shaping, rate-limiting, tc, htb

I would like to configure AQM PIE by using tc-qdisc, but at the same time I would like to limit the bandwidth to 1Mb/s.

I have used similar configuration with fq_codel, i.e. I have limited the bandwidth by using htb, and later configured fq_codel for the leaf class, as it is done in this example https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/879656-qos-in-linux-with-tc-and-filters

So for pie I do:

```
 tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle 1: root htb default 11
 tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1000kbit ceil 1000kbit
 tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate 1000kbit ceil
   1000kbit 
 tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:11 pie
```

However I get "qdisc uknown" message and for example when I try to change any arguments of pie, I get an error: Unknown qdisc "pie", hence option "alpha" is unparsable.

Is it possible to use pie and limit the bandwidth at the same time?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The problem was solved when I updated the Linux version. So probably it was linked to the traffic shaping version.

Answer (score 2):

PIE was added to the Linux kernel in version 3.14 (https://www.linux.com/news/linux-314-release-no-pi-new-pie-fights-bufferbloat), so you need a Linux version >= 3.14 in order to run PIE. In order to configure PIE, you also need an up-to-date version of the tc utility, which is part of iproute2. You can download the appropriate version of iproute2 for your Linux kernel [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/).